# Separate shared_task functions of celery in a separate method

Tags: python, celery

I have below celery code and I want to separate all the shared_task functions in separate module.

```
class myTask():
    def xyz():
       .....
       np = task_to_do.signature(
            (params))
        np.apply_async(task_id=uuid)

@shared_task
def task_to_do(params):
    return 'something'
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: @2ps Question is: How to separate shared_task function into a separate module? Thanks.